# Unable to create property with name containing literal 'password'

Tags: orbeon

In the properties-local.xml file, I've created some properties. These properties are used to form the URL to where the form data will be sent. The properties are as follows:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.protocol">http</property>

<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.username">uname</property>
<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.pass">gesundheit</property>

<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.host">127.0.0.1:8090</property>

<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.api.path">ekualiti-kc/remoting/api/orbeonforms</property>
<property as="xs:string" name="streamlyne.api.action">saveFormData</property>
```

The send property is as follows:

```
<property as="xs:string" name="oxf.fr.detail.process.save-draft.S2S_Forms.*">   
    save
    then send(
        uri = "{xxf:property('streamlyne.protocol')}://{xxf:property('streamlyne.username')}:{xxf:property('streamlyne.pass')}@{xxf:property('streamlyne.host')}/{xxf:property('streamlyne.api.path')}/{xxf:property('streamlyne.api.action')}/{xxf:get-request-parameter('propsalID')}",
        replace  = "none",
        method   = "post",
        content  = "xml",
        annotate = "id"
    )
    then success-message("save-success")
    recover error-message("save-error")
</property>
```

The above configuration worked fine.

**ISSUE:**

I wanted to give the name of the password property as `streamlyne.password`. When I tried doing so, the save action failed. So I changed the name to `streamlyne.password1`. It failed again. Is there any convention, not to put the literal `password` in a property name attribute? I know this sounds silly. But I'm quite sure renaming the property name to `pass` worked pretty well!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, `xxf:property()` doesn't return the value properties that contains the string "password". This is done on purpose to prevent form authors from accessing the value of properties you want Orbeon Forms to know about, but you wouldn't necessarily want form authors to know about, say `oxf.http.ssl.keystore.password`.

So in your case, I'd just recommend using another name (say `pass` as you suggested, or `secret`).